# How can I insert PHP code in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I tried the `views_php` but I have no luck. Any link to its documentation?

I want to add some custom field with PHP code inside it but the one I did return nothing. Please see the attached picture.[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the `php filter`.

Comment: Can't find that PHP filter.

Comment: Oh sorry I got that. Already enabled.

Comment: No need of enabling php filter module.

Comment: Oh I thought I need that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can add php code using views_php

Add field in views global
[image: Add field in views]
Then add code you need is in Output code sector. I thing here is the problem for you. you add php code to 'Value code'. 
[image: Add php code in output field]
Then look at the preview. it's done!!!!!!
[image: Look at the preview]

Comment: The problem is that code in the Output field works, but not code in the Value field.