# Views PHP references

Tags: views

I would like to use Views PHP module in my Drupal Site.

But I don't have any idea on how to use this and I can't find good tutorial for this module.
Anyone who can suggest any references or videos for Views PHP Tutorial?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about document references or tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists good documentation in [Project Page of Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module and Documentation under [Read Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1686948) link in project page..

- [How to Use Views PHP](https://drupal.org/node/1686948) in views filter
- [How to Use Views PHP](https://drupal.org/node/2088039) as Views Output Field..

Some existing answers and tutorials which can explain better you can find below..

[How can I insert PHP code in Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54130/how-can-i-insert-php-code-in-views)

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/03/10/drupal-7-add-php-field-to-view/